# Detect touch from an array of UIViews

Tags: uiview, touch

I am working on a view controllers that has many UIview in a grid layout. Those views has some interaction (like buttons etc). But on touching that view, I want a new view controller to appear. 
I cannot find a way to check for a touch from these views. There's a method CGRectContainsPoint... but I have multiple UIViews.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

   CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
   if ( CGRectContainsPoint(subview1.frame, point))
   {
     //show viewcontroller1
   }
   if ( CGRectContainsPoint(subview2.frame, point))
   {
     //show viewcontroller2 
   }
}
```

This way you should be able to determine which subview is touched.

The idea is that first you get your coordinates based on the self.view and then you can compare them with the subviews of the original view.

I think other possible solutoions could be:

1 Use keyValueObserving http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

or
2 NSNotificatonCenter messages http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

With both methods you can let your (sub)views signal your viewcontroller when your subview detect a touch and let the viewcontroller act accordingly.

Comment: My view contains two buttons, so on tapping those buttons will touchesBegan gets called or touchUpInside? Moreover grid contains 12 views, so i'll have to use a loop in touchesBegan method...but is it an efficient way to run that loop every time a touch is detected?

Comment: There are two things that can happen, when your buttons are touched the selector that is coupled with it will be called. Otherwise if the view is touched the touchesbegan will be invoked. I agree that it might not be the most efficient way of handling this problem. I'll edit my answer to describe two different ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of tackling this problem would be to add gesture recognizers to your views to pick up taps:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_method_:)];
    [_view_ addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecogniser];
    [tapGestureRecogniser release];
```

This would call *method* whenever the *view* is tapped.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this. But still the problem persists, these views have buttons to be tapped. On adding tap getsures to complete view, the action coupled to these buttons doesn't get called, instead it crashes.